# Most optimal way to parse querystring within a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have a querystring alike value set in a plain string. I started to split string to get value out but I started to wonder that I can proabably write this in one line instead. Could you please advice if there is more optimal way to do this?

I am trying to read "123" and "abc" like in Request.QueryString but from normal string.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string qs = "id=123&xx=abc";
    string[] urlInfo = qs.Split('&');
    string id = urlInfo[urlInfo.Length - 2];
    Response.Write(id.ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;

NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
Response.Write(query["id"]);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 27):

Look at [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx). Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I knew there had to be better way to do this. I just was looking from wrong place. Thanks!

Comment: @jpkeisala- That's the joy of a large framework. It is sometimes hard to find the right class.

Answer (score 3):

RichardOD is on it with  [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx) but don't forget to look at `TryParse`.

You can TryParse [int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx), [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)s etc

[How do you test your Request.QueryString[] variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349742/how-do-you-test-your-request-querystring-variables)