# Capture Data From Web Address

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to store my web address in a variable, but I keep getting an error of

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection' to 'string'

ANd this is my syntax

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetKeyInfo();
}

protected void GetKeyInfo()
{
    //The below line is the problem line
    string fulladdress = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query;
    Response.Write(fulladdress);
    string parsed = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(fulladdress);
}
```

**EDIT**
This is the address shown in browswer where I am attempting to run this
http://www.internaltesting.com/PassingDataTest/default.aspx?Information=https://XXX.XXX.X.XXX/all?token=1&cid=1832&employeeid=16432

And this is full error that is given

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>   Line 29:         string fulladdress = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query;
>   Line 30:         Response.Write(fulladdress);
>   Line 31:         var parsed = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(fulladdress);
>   Line 32:         string token = parsed["token"];
>   Line 33:         string employeeid = parsed["employeeid"];

**EDIT**
Is this the line from web.config you are after

> ```
> <compilation debug="true">
>   <assemblies>
>     <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
>   </assemblies>
> </compilation>
> ```

Comment: the error is telling you what the problem is.. you are trying to assign a List<T> to a string what if you change string to `var parsed` it will compile or change your code to `NameValueCollection parsed = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("myAddress");` and add to the using at the top of your class the following `using System.Collections.Specialized;` does google work in your neck of the woods..? look at the msdn documentation -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MethodMan - var throws an error also

Comment: no it does not.. I tested it and it compiles.. please paste an example of what fulladdress is when you debug the code..

Comment: you probably are not even using the debugger and secondly the value of `fullAddress` is probably `string.Empty`

Comment: @FunFlyWhiteGuy what version of C#/.NET are you using? The support for `var` has came out a long time ago.

Comment: Do you have a part in your `web.config` which looks like `<system.codedom><compilers><compiler ...` and if so could you paste that part? Does it contain a node that says `<providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v2.0"/>`?

Comment: also read the following this should be something that you should be doing on your end {MSDN Implicitly Typed Local Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) I also told you that if you didn't want to use the word `var` that you would need to declare your variable as the following `NameValueCollection parsed = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("myAddress");` and add to the top of the .cs file 
`using System.Collections.Specialized`

Comment: also right click on the project and click Properties and tell us what .net version you are coding this in..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` returns a `NameValueCollection` containing **all** the query string parameters, it's not a single string.

```
var parsed = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(fulladdress);
string singleParam = parsed.Get("OneParam");
```

or for ancient .NET/C# version that don't support `var`:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parsed = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(fulladdress);
string singleParam = parsed.Get("OneParam");
```

See also:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString Method) and [How to read the query string params of a ASP.NET raw URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676975/how-to-read-the-query-string-params-of-a-asp-net-raw-url)

Comment: This gives me an error of The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found

Comment: Which .NET / Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: VS2010 - not sure which .net...

Comment: so @FunFlyWhiteGuy you can't click the `about VisualStudio` in the help menu to see what version you're using.. ?

Comment: Version 10.0.40219.1