# How to extract certain values from url using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most optimal way to parse querystring within a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206548/most-optimal-way-to-parse-querystring-within-a-string-in-c-sharp)

I have the following url which I get as an input.

```
string strInput = @"http://ping.com/default.aspx?
val=88.998~98.3399&val=12.55_14.55&val=8.299&val=7.299&val=9.299";
```

I want to extract values 88.998 ,98.3399 and 7.299.Sometimes these values might be empty.
I tried the pattern `@"(?\=<val1>\d+\~$)"` for extracting 88.998 , but it didn't work. And also I am not able to get other two values 98.3399 and 7.299.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel! Use a library. What you want to do is called *URL parsing*, specifically, the bit after the question mark is called the *querystring*.

Comment: What is your actual problem? Trying to pars Url with Regex adds more than standard +1 problem - ["want to do it with regex - now you have two problems"](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).

Answer (score 2):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206659/284795

> You can do it this way:
>
> ```
> using System.Collections.Specialized;
>
> NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
> Response.Write(query["id"]);
> ```
>
> Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for finding the right question. Consider editing and adding the remaining part to use `String.Split("~")` to separate pairs of numbers from query parameter...

Comment: Looks like 100% copy paste from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1206659/284795