# Use "as" operator to test integer type in Page.RouteData.Values

Tags: c#, .net

In my code I have registered route in global.asax like the following:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.MapPageRoute(
    "product",
    "product/{id}",
    "~/index.aspx"
);
```

then in my index.aspx page, I want to test the {id} value whether it is integer:

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values["id"] as int? != null)   
//always evaluate as null even id is an integer in the URL, ex: /product/1
```

I understand I can use some other methods (such as int.TryParse or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349742/how-do-you-test-your-request-querystring-variables) ) to achieve the same goal, but would using a "as" make sense in this case?

Comment: You have [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.100).aspx) operator as well. (pun intended :))

Comment: If you simply pass it in, the model binder will do its best - if it is the only overload of your action and the value cannot be converted, you will get an exception.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, `is` would probably not work if the `id` value was stored as a string (which I'm going to guess it is). In that case it's probably better to `TryParse`.

Comment: @Link but so will the `as` operator. Anyway, if the goal is to check the **value** (rather than type) the only way is TryParse indeed.

Comment: @user: `is` still works even id is string

Comment: I reckon `Page.RouteData.Values["id"]` is not an `integer`.

Comment: Thanks guy. I think as and is would behave the same in this case as they both test the type not the value. So I agree that probably TryParse is the way to go.

Comment: @CuongLe It works as in it won't crash, it will just always return false.  The goal of the OP appears to be determining if a string value can be parsed into a valid number; `is` won't tell you that.  `"0" is int` will be `false`, not `true`.

Comment: @CuongLe In my mind "not crashing" isn't the same as "it works".  "it works" means, performs the desired action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to go depends on what is really stored in `Values["id"]`. If it is in fact an `int`, you can test for `int` with `Values["id"] is int`. The `Values[]` property is typed as object. Therefore it can be `null`. But this does NOT mean, that the stored `int` is a `Nullable<int>`. (see my update below.)

If you assign an `int` (and all other non-reference types) to an object variable or property, it will be boxed. I.e. it will be packed into an object of the corresponding type. `int` or `System.Int32` exists as value type as well as a boxed and immutable `System.Int32` reference type. Because of its immutability, you don't notice that it is a reference type. An `int` can be boxed with `object obj = 5;` and unboxed with `int i = (int)obj;`.

On the other hand, if the id was stored as string then you would have to convert it to a number

```
int id;
if (Int32.TryParse((string)Page.RouteData.Values["id"], out id)) {
    // use id here
}
```

---

UPDATE:

There seems to be some confusion with `null` and `Nullable<T>`.

```
int? i; // Same as Nullable<int> or Nullable<System.Int32> or System.Int32?
object obj;
bool test;

i = null;
test = i.HasValue; // ==> false
test = i == null;  // ==> true

// Now comes the strange part

obj = 5;           // The int is boxed here.
// Debugger shows type of obj as "object {int}"
test = obj is int;   // ==> true
test = obj is int?;   // ==> true
int x = (int)obj;  // ==> 5, the int is unboxed here.

// But

obj = null;
// Debugger shows type of obj as "object"
test = obj is int; // ==> false
test = obj is int?; // ==> false
test = obj == null; // ==> true

// And
i = 5;
obj = i; // i is a Nullable<int>
// Debugger shows type of obj as "object {int}"
test = obj is int; // ==> true
test = obj is int?; // ==> true
test = obj == null; // ==> false

i = null;
obj = i;
// Debugger shows type of obj as "object"
test = obj is int; // ==> false
test = obj is int?; // ==> false
test = obj == null; // ==> true
```

Both `obj is int` and `obj is int?` return `true` if `obj` contains an `int` number but both return false if `obj` contains `null`! A `null` `Nullable<int>` is converted to `(object)null` when asssigned to `obj` and is no more `Nullable<int>`.

The debugger shows the type of `obj` as `object {int}` when there is a number stored, no matter whether an `int` or an `int?` was assigned! The type of `obj` is `object` when `null` is stored.

So Chuong Le is in fact right!

Comment: Thanks. good explanation and I like that your code is straightforward.

Comment: *The Values[] property is typed as object. Therefore it can be null* is not correct, try: `object a = 1; bool flag b = a is int?`, flag still true

Comment: @CuongLe: You are confusing two things. You can assign `object a = null;`. This is NOT the same as `int? i = null;`! An `int?` with no value in it can be compared to `null` and yields `true`, but `null` is not a `Nullable<int>`! The Comparison works because the `==` operator is overloaded in `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: @CuongLe: Im am sorry, you are in fact right. I updated my post and added the results of tests I have made. The confusion comes from that fact that there is no difference between a boxed `int` and a boxed `int?` and both `obj is int` and `obj is int?` return `true`!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you use `Int.TryParse`, because the value is most likely going to be a string. Don't use the `Int.Parse` because you will also have to handle the exception and you generally want to avoid coding things that could throw exceptions (even if you're handling them).

Using `as` is not really a good solution since it forces you to use nullable `int`; if you take the `is` route, then it's <strike>almost</strike> guaranteed not to work when the passed in value is a `string` type.

Regarding the `is` debate, I ran this in VS:

```
string value = "42";
object answerToUniverse = value;
if (answerToUniverse is int)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's an integer!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's NOT an integer!");
}
```

The result was: It's **NOT** an integer!

Comment: Thanks @Lirik, you justify the "is" debate, want to vote you up too but I can't yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you actually want to do this,

```
var idString = Page.RouteData.Values["id"] as string;
int id;
if (int.TryParse(idString, out id))
{
   // id is now a valid number 
}
else
{
   // your types are confused
}
```

Comment: But if `Page.RouteData.Values["id"]` is not a string won't it give `null` back?

Comment: You don't need the isnullorwhitespace check. If the string is null or whitespace then `tryparse` will just return false.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to check the **value** rather than the **type** meaning you don't really care what the type is.

In such case, this is the best approach I can recommend:

```
object idValue = Page.RouteData.Values["id"];
int dummy;
if (idValue != null && Int32.TryParse(idValue.ToString(), out dummy))
{
    //value is integer!
}
```

This way it doesn't matter what the type is; if it's integer, double, string or even complex type with proper `ToString()` override, it will work.

Comment: `This way it doesn't matter what the type is` unless it's `null`, then you'll get a null reference exception.  Additionally, if it really is an integer (I'm pretty sure it's not though) you'd be turning it into a string and then parsing it again.  That's generally not a good idea.  If it's possible that the value really is an integer you should check for it and then cast.

Comment: @Servy I do check for null first: `if (idValue != null && ...)` so no risk for error. This way is good only if the type is unknown, if it's known then of course casting is ideal.

Comment: This way is okay if you know that the value is actually a string.  If it's not you should check if it's an `int`, and cast it if it is, do the same for the other numeric types, and then if none of those succeed then call `ToString` and try to parse it.  That is, in essense, what `Convert.ToInt` does, although it will throw an exception if none of the possible options work rather than failing gracefully.  In practice though, you should never be in the situation where you sometimes have an integer and sometimes have a string with an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

`as` is a safe cast.  It will try and cast the provided value to the desired type, returning `null` instead of throwing an exception when a standard cast would.

Therefore unless Page.RouteData.Values["id"] was an integer object this would not work and you need to user the alternative methods you suggested.

One was could be to use an extension method

```
public static class IntExtensions {
   public static int? AsInt(this string source) {
     int result;
     return (int.TryParse(source,out result)) ? (int?)null : result;
   }

   public static bool IsInt(this string source) {
     return source.AsInt.HasValue;
   }
}
```

Allowing you to do

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values["id"].IsInt())
```