# Is there a way to protect against tampered QueryStrings or missing QueryString?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm not really sure about this question but is there a way to protect against tampered/missing QueryStrings in ASP.NET?

Example: I have this URL

```
http://localhost:56842/TCKT/Configs.aspx?type=view
```

From Code Behind I'm getting the value like below:

```
Request.QueryString["type"];
```

I know how to protect against missing values but I need to find out if there is a way to protect against missing QueryString meaning

```
?type=
```

Is missing all together.

I have seen people doing

```
Request.QueryString["type"].IsEmpty()
```

But is not working for me and I'm not really sure if this is possible. Any help you could provide will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["type"]);
```

Somewhat similar for [specific types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349742/how-do-you-test-your-request-querystring-variables)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, much appreciatted

Answer (score 0):

```
string type = Request.QueryString["type"] ?? "default"
```

To get the value or default when the value is null.