# How to extract an ID number from a URL string in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract an ID from a URL and running into some issues.  The URL's will look something like this:

> http://www.website.com/news/view.aspx?id=95
>
> http://www.website.com/news/view.aspx?id=20&ReturnURL=%2fnews%2fview.aspx%3fid%3d20

I am trying to return back the number following "?id=" and nothing after the number.  I will then convert it to an INT in reference to another table.  Any suggestions as how to do this properly?

Comment: I don't understand, the url is a column in your database? Or are you trying to get the value from the current url in a webapp?

Comment: Find instance of `?ID=` in string return everything from that point to a `&` or end of string.

Comment: Sorry, yes this is a column within a database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `charindex` to find the position of `?id` and `stuff` to remove the characters that is before `?id`. Then you use `left` to return the characters to the next `&`

```
declare @T table
(
  URL varchar(100)
);

insert into @T values
('http://www.website.com/news/view.aspx?id=95'),
('http://www.website.com/news/view.aspx?id=20&ReturnURL=%2fnews%2fview.aspx%3fid%3d20');


select left(T2.URL, charindex('&', T2.URL) - 1) as ID
from @T as T
  cross apply (select stuff(T.URL, 1, charindex('?id', T.URL) + 3, '')+'&') as T2(URL);
```

Comment: This appears to be working for me.  I have modified it a bit to fit my solution, but the results appear to be what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: it won't work for urls like ```http://www.website.com/news/view.aspx?a=1&id=95```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option that you can use when you want to find the value of any parameter value within a URL, it also supports parsing text values that contain a URL

```
DECLARE @Param varchar(50) = 'event'
DECLARE @Data varchar(8000) = 'User Logged into  https://my.website.org/default.aspx?id=3066&event=49de&event=true from ip'

DECLARE @ParamIndex int = (select PatIndex('%'+@param+'=%', @Data)+LEN(@param)+1)
-- @ParamValueSubstring chops off everthing before the first instance of the parameter value
DECLARE @ParamValueSubstring varchar(8000) = SubString(@Data, @ParamIndex, 8000)

SELECT @ParamValueSubstring as ParamSubstring

DECLARE @SpaceIndex int = (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', @ParamValueSubstring))-1
DECLARE @AmpIndex int = (SELECT CHARINDEX('&', @ParamValueSubstring))-1
DECLARE @valueLength int = -1

-- find first instance of ' ' or & after parameter value
IF @SpaceIndex = -1
  SET @valueLength = @AmpIndex
ELSE IF @AmpIndex = -1
  SET @valueLength = @SpaceIndex
ELSE IF @SpaceIndex < @AmpIndex 
  SET @valueLength = @SpaceIndex
ELSE  
  SET @valueLength = @AmpIndex 

IF(@valueLength = -1) -- check to see if there was no space or '&' following the parameter value
BEGIN
   SET @valueLength = 8000
END

select Left(@ParamValueSubstring, @valueLength) as ParamValue

-- approach similar to idea function found here http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what you're asking. Are you asking how to get the value of id from the url when you are in the `asp.net` application? Then in the code behind you can

In c#

```
string id = Request.QueryString["id"]; // returns null if id not found
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[From this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349742/how-do-you-test-your-request-querystring-variables) Try this for integers:

```
int id;
if (!int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id))
{
  // error case
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me. Someone added the tag `asp.net` which leads me to believe he wants to get the value from the current url. It's not very clear.

Comment: I noticed that someone suggested the tag so I removed it, definitely not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in an SQL function, like this:

```
declare @URL varchar(100)

--set @URL = 'http://www.website.com/news/view.aspx?id=95'
set @URL = 'http://www.website.com/news/view.aspx?id=20&ReturnURL=%2fnews%2fview.aspx%3fid%3d20'

Set @URL = CASE charindex('&',@URL) 
    WHEN 0 then @URL else substring(@url,1,charindex('&',@URL)-1) end

select @URL,SUBSTRING(@URL,CHARINDEX('?id=',@URL)+4,99)
```

Both examples are in there, comment either one to see result