# how send the value of the selected row in gridview to next page..,

Tags: c#, asp.net

below is the code which is written in the Page where we want it..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
   {
      int rowIndex = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]);
      GridView GridView1 = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("gv1");
      GridViewRow row;
      row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
      lblid.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
      lblname.Text = (row.FindControl("lblName") as Label).Text;
      lblmt.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
      lblyer.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass values across the pages in ASP.net Insted of Session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956027/how-to-pass-values-across-the-pages-in-asp-net-insted-of-session)

Comment: Put the code by which you are coming to this code. Ideally you should send values from the gridview itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, consider

1. Session state
2. Query string

**Session state**

If you are going to send data between pages, you could consider the use of [Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx).

> ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a
>   user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application. HTTP is
>   a stateless protocol. This means that a Web server treats each HTTP
>   request for a page as an independent request. The server retains no
>   knowledge of variable values that were used during previous requests.
>   ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during
>   a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist
>   variable values for the duration of that session. By default, ASP.NET
>   session state is enabled for all ASP.NET applications. Best of all, it
>   is easy!

Put data in (for example on default1.aspx)

```
Session["ID"] = lblid.Text;
Session["Name"] = lblname.Text;
Session["Amt"] = lblmt.Text;
Session["Year"] = lblyer.Text;
```

Get it out (for example on default2.aspx)

```
string Id= Session["ID"] 
string Name= Session["Name"] 
string Amout = Session["Amt"] 
string year = Session["Year"]
```

**Query string**

If you are sending small amounts of data (eg id=4), it may be more practical to use query string variables.

You should explore the use of the query string variables, e.g.

```
http://www.domain.com?param1=data1&param2=data2
```

You can then get the data out like

```
string param1 = Request.QueryString["param2"]; // value will be data1
string param2 = Request.QueryString["param2"]; // value will be data2
```

You can use something like [How do you test your Request.QueryString[] variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349742/how-do-you-test-your-request-querystring-variables)? to get the data out.

If you want to know more about  querystring variables check out their [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)